# Applying for job while 3/4 done with MS program

Tags: masters, job-search

I am currently a MS student finishing my last (2nd) year. I have just applied to a top company of my field in my city (perhaps the nation as well). I did a video, phone, and on-site interview. They understand that I have just 1 class left next semester, but also need to finish my thesis (which is maybe 25% done?). I have informed them that I can work a full 40hrs a week (I am actually currently working about 35 hrs on top of 2 classes, TAing, thesis work). I have received an offer to start in January that is generally quite high for a new MS grad in my field. To be honest, I am much more interested in the work I would be doing at this company.

Should I take the offer and start working while taking the class/work on thesis? Or don't take it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually a masters thesis is a full time job, especially closer to the end of the thesis. Honestly, I would not recommend working 40h/week on top of working on a masters thesis, as long as the fields are not closely related. But of course this depends on individual factors which we can not appraise without knowing you and your thesis / course work.

Some questions which might help:

- How much of your thesis can be finished before January?
- Will it be possible to reduce the working hours to complete your studies if necessary (without being paid during that time)?
- How well can you handle stress?
- Would it be possible to start with 20-30h/week whilst you have to study?

In the long run, it is not a good idea to screw your thesis for a job. It is the most important grade! When people apply for a position at my lab, I am mainly looking at their thesis topic and grade - the rest is less important.

Maybe you can twist it another way: At our university it is common that students are doing their thesis in cooperation with a company - maybe you could switch your thesis topic and combine job and thesis.